# Dependency injection in servlet on embedded Jetty

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I have embedded Jetty server and I added servlet mapping.

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/");
context.addServlet(RegisterServlet.class, "/user/register");
```

I want to make the Dependency Injection in servlet with spring framework configuring ApplicationContext.xml. It should work the same as here:

```
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
private Service service;
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
    service = context.getBean("service", Service.class);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
}
```

but without using context.getBean("service").

Answer (score 2):

This way you can have the control of servlet instantiation

```java
Server server = new Server(port);
ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
handler.addServletWithMapping(new ServletHolder(new RegisterServlet()), "/user/register");
server.setHandler(handler);
server.start();
```

So now you can get the servlet instance from a DI container of something